# UISearchbar unable to remove text border

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I set a transparent image to a UISearchBar in order to show the background of the view behind it. For some reason it caused a strange truncated blue border to appear on the text field.

Here is how it looks:
[image]

Any idea from where did it come from? Any way of removing it?

Comment: did you tried this [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't work. Still blue border.